# Finding the equation of the tangent line to the curve $(3x+1)/(7x-1)$ at any point $P$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, tangent-line

So, the question is to find the tangent line to the curve
$\ (3x+1) / (7x - 1) $ at any specific point P.

So I start by derivating the function and get: $\ -10 / (7x - 1)^2 $.

I now know that I'm supposed to use the formula: Y - Y0 = K(X - X0) to get the function. However, am I just supposed to pick a random point, probably by choosing some X-value, on the curve or is it important which point i use?

Comment: The  book did not specify any point?

Comment: No, so I suppose I could just decide to get the tangent at x = 1, but I wanted to check here if there some more procedure to it than that.

Comment: If a point is not specified, you cannot just pick $x=1$. Either a point is given in the problem, or otherwise keep it general as in the answer of Gimusi

Comment: @lykkinski Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $K=f'(x)$ at the given point where you are looking for the tangent.

Note that for the given function

$$f'(x)= \frac{-10}{(7 x -1)^2}$$

If you don't have a specific point the general form for the tangent at $P(x_0,y_0)$ is

$$(y-y_0)=\frac{-10}{(7 x_0 - 1)^2}(x-x_0)$$

Comment: Sorry, wrote the wrong function in my question. It is corrected now.

Comment: Nevermind I've updated, it is not so important for the concept!

Answer (score 0):

In general the tangent lines at different points of a function are different lines, so it has little sense to speak of a tangent to a curve without specify a point  of tangency, or al least a point where the line have to passes.

In general, fixed the value of $x=a$ in the domain, we find a point of the graph of the function,  $P=(a,f(a))$, that in your case is
$$
f(a)=\frac{3a+1}{7a-1}
$$
and the slope of the tangent is the value of the derivative at this point $K=f'(a)$, in your case:
$$K=\frac{-10}{(7a-1)^2}$$

So the tangent line has equation:
$$
y-f(a)=K(x-a)
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I know it's not part of my original question but why isn't the function defined at x = 1?. Won't we just get  f(1) = 2 / 3 ?

Comment: Sorry. My mistake... the function is defined at $x=1$.